# Export Pegasus Mailing List to Thunderbird

Tags: email, email-client

Is it possible to export a Pegasus Mailing List (not Address Book) to Thunderbird?

Answer (score 0):

http://community.pmail.com/forums/thread/36737.aspx

It's a text file, just grep for e-mail addresses.